# How to shrink or manage an image's size in bytes

Tags: python-imaging-library, google-vision

Python 3.6.6, Pillow 5.2.0

The Google Vision API has a size limit of 10485760 bytes.

When I'm working with a PIL Image, and save it to Bytes, it is hard to predict what the size will be.  Sometimes when I try to resize it to have smaller height and width, the image size as bytes gets bigger.

I've tried experimenting with modes and formats, to understand their impact on size, but I'm not having much luck getting consistent results.

So I start out with a rawImage that is Bytes obtained from some user uploading an image (meaning I don't know much about what I'm working with yet).

```
rawImageSize = sys.getsizeof(rawImage)
if rawImageSize >= 10485760:
   imageToShrink = Image.open(io.BytesIO(rawImage))

   ## do something to the image here to shrink it
   # ... mystery code ...
   ## ideally, the minimum amount of shrinkage necessary to get it under 10485760

   rawBuffer = io.BytesIO()

   # possibly convert to RGB first
   shrunkImage.save(rawBuffer, format='JPEG') # PNG files end up bigger after this resizing (!?)
   rawImage = rawBuffer.getvalue()

   print(sys.getsizeof(rawImage))
```

To shrink it I've tried getting a shrink ratio and then simply resizing it:

```
    shrinkRatio =  10485760.0  / float(rawImageSize)

    imageWidth, imageHeight = pilImage.size
    shrunkImage = imageToShrink.resize((int(imageWidth * shrinkRatio),
                                        int(imageHeight * shrinkRatio)), Image.LANCZOS)
```

Of course I could use a sufficiently small and somewhat arbitrary thumbnail size instead. I've thought about iterating thumbnail sizes until a combination takes me below the maximum bytes size threshold.  I'm guessing the bytes size varies based on the color depth and mode and (?) I got from the end user that uploaded the original image.  And that brings me to my questions:

Can I predict the size in bytes a PIL Image will be before I convert it for consumption by Google Vision?  What is the best way to manage that size in bytes before I convert it?

Comment: Good question! I assume it also depends on the image itself, e.g. whether there are a lot of features that can be safely removed by JPEG compression or not. What I would suggest is to take and/or generate a few really big images and shrink them in a loop, keeping track of a graph of file size over shrink ratio to learn if there is a ratio that would 'usually' work.

Answer (score 0):

First all, you probably don't need to maximize to the 10M limit posed by Google Vision API. In most case, a much smaller file will be just fine, and faster.

In addition to that, you may want to keep in mind that the aspect ratio might lead to different result. See this, https://www.mlreader.com/prepare-image-for-google-vision-api